# Check that a csv file has the correct column names python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that I'm uploading to a database, Id like to compare the headings/columns to a list so that I can make sure its the correct csv file being inserted into the database without having to open the csv file
so if I have the following `Name Surname  Age Height` it must be compared to the csv headings if its not correct display some message.

Comment: What's your *specific* question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pd.read_csv` with `nrows=0`. Below is an example.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

mystr = StringIO("""col1,col2,col3
val1,val2,val3""")

check_list = ['Name', 'Surname', 'Age', 'Height']
df_cols = pd.read_csv(mystr, nrows=0)

df_cols_list = df_cols.columns.tolist()

assert df_cols_list == check_list, "Columns are misaligned: {0} vs {1}".format(df_cols_list, check_list)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-32-3638118067e8> in <module>()
#      10 df_cols_list = df_cols.columns.tolist()
#      11 
# ---> 12 assert df_cols_list == check_list, "Columns are misaligned: {0} vs {1}".format(df_cols_list, check_list)

# AssertionError: Columns are misaligned: ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'] vs ['Name', 'Surname', 'Age', 'Height']
```